# App fails to work after a few years

Tags: facebook, authentication, legacy

I have had an app for a long time now, there are a few hundred people who play it daily but I no longer actively do Facebook development.

Today I got a bunch of emails complaining it no longer works, sure enough it's just a blank page.

I don't want to rewrite anything and am looking for the bare minimum I can do to get things rolling.

I have no desire to upgrade my Facebook library. I use `$facebook->require_login()` which seems to be where the problem is.

It is an FBML app and viewing source shows that it has outputted the correct JavaScript redirect it just simply does nothing.

Previously I had turned a bunch of options off in the app settings to correct other problems created by constant updates but now it seems they no longer give that option.

Comment: FBML is very quickly becoming depreciated. It sounds like you'd better hand off the app development to someone who wants to work on it, or rewrite without FBML. I'm sure there's a quick fix though; be patient and someone will be along.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding your application? (code, for example). By the way, have you considered the possibility of the error being related to your using of an older version?, there might have been some kind of change in the way the front-end works, and your SDK might think its an error of some kind. Oh, and error logs, if any, would be good as well.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is related to using an older version however from what I can see it would be a lot of digging around to upgrade to the new version. That looks like it will be the case... The app doesn't make money, at least not enough that anyone would take it over who didn't want to basically volunteer. I would like to keep it running though just for all the players who have kept with it for years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php is about all you need to know.

I didn't upgrade some functionality (some fql queries etc) simple because they are not critical to the application although I don't think that would take much longer.

Less than an hour to get things rolling.